# Jquery - Toggle class on click of button / Remove class on click of body and other buttons with same class

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click, removeclass, toggleclass

I have different buttons with the same class. Each button have a "+" with :after. I want to show a "-" if a button is clicked and remove the "-" when one of the other button is clicked, the rest of the window is clicked or the same button is clicked again.

This is what I have so far:

```
var removeClass = true; 
$(".button").click(function () {
    /* $(".button").removeClass('bclose'); */
    $(this).toggleClass('bclose');
    removeClass = false;
});

$(".button").click(function() {
    removeClass = false;
});

$("html").click(function () {
    if (removeClass) {
        $(".button").removeClass('bclose');
    }
    removeClass = true;
});
```

The "-" & bclose class removes if you click the window or the button again, but if you click one of the other button the "-" doesn't remove.

If i add

```
$(".button").removeClass('bclose');
```

it works fine but not if you click the same button again.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tjga5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".button").not(this).removeClass('bclose');
    $(this).toggleClass('bclose');

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tjga5/1/)

Comment: Very nice, I always forget about the not +1

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code:

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".button").not(this).removeClass('bclose');
    $(this).toggleClass('bclose');
});


$("body").click(function () {
    $(".button").removeClass('bclose');
});
```

### --DEMO--

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `bclose` class then add the class to the recently clicked one. You can do it like this:

```
$(".button").click(function () {
   $(".button").removeClass('bclose'); 
   $(this).addClass('bclose');


   removeClass = false;
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tjga5/6/)

Comment: he/she also wants it to remove the class if it is already added